# Why are some command options with one dash and others are with two dashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some command options are with one dash e.g. `ruby -c` (check syntax) and `ruby --copyright` (print copyright). Is there any pattern to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are known as short and long options. Which name/format a developer uses for options of his program is totally up to him.

However, there are some widespread conventions. Like `-v`/`--version` for printing version number, `-h`/`--help` for printing usage instructions, etc.

Sadly, most commandline tools on OSX seem not to conform to `-v`/`-h`.

Good CLI (command-line interface) design dictates that options of a program that are most useful should have two formats, short and long. You use short format in your everyday life (because it's faster to type).

```
ps aux | grep ruby
```

Long ones are for scripts that you write and rarely touch (they're easier to read and understand).

```
mongod --logpath /path/to/logs --dbpath /path/to/db --fork --smallfiles
```

Many less used options may have only the long version (because, you know, there are only 26 letters in latin alphabet).

Answer (score 1):

On many rails commands there is a pattern.  One dash is an abbreviation for a two dash option, e.g. `rspec -o FILE` is a synonym for `rspec --out FILE`.